# Fast method to retrieve contour mask from a binary mask in Python

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, binary, edges

I want to make a realtime application, which involves finding the edges of a binary mask. I need something fast, without GPU if possible, that runs hopefully below 0.0005 secs per image, with size (1000,1000). I will be using the following example of a binary image ,with size (1000,1000).

(Code to replicate:)

```
import numpy as np
im=np.zeros((1000,1000),dtype=np.uint8)
im[400:600,400:600]=255
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smMAN.png)

The first logical way to do things fast was to use the OpenCV library:

```
import cv2
timeit.timeit(lambda:cv2.Laplacian(im,cv2.CV_8U),number=100)/100
0.0011617112159729003
```

which as expected resulted in:
[laplacian](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7xUh.png)

I found this way very time consuming. After this I tried findContours:

```
 def usingcontours(im):
    points=np.transpose(cv2.findContours(im,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)[1][0])
    tmp=np.zeros_like(im)
    tmp[tuple(points)]=255
    return tmp 
timeit.timeit(lambda:usingcontours(im),number=100)/100
0.0009052801132202148
```

which gave the same result as above.
This is better, but still not as good as I would like. I moved on with usage of numpy, to approximate laplacian using gradient, as last resort, although I knew it would be worse:

```
def usinggradient(im):
    tmp=np.gradient(im)
    return ((tmp[0]+tmp[1])>0).astype(np.uint8)
timeit.timeit(lambda:usinggradient(im),number=100)/100
0.018681130409240722
```

So, has anyone any further idea on how I can accelerate my algorithm? I emphasize that I want this algorithm to be used for binary images, so I guess there must be a better implementation.

Comment: You can do this with some NumPy and Scipy morphological erosion and bitwise operations  NumPy. Check out `scipy.ndimage.morphology.binary_dilation` and the `np.logical_*` functions.

Comment: `1000 x 1000 / 0.0005s = 2 x 10^9 pixels/second` -- that's 1-2 clock cycles per pixel, and even with vectorization and parallelization that doesn't give much to work with.

Comment: @DanMašek 2 x 10^9 pixels/second means for a bitwise image 2x10^9 bits/second. Assuming that a good program uses all cores, which I believe is possible, in an 8 core 2GHz CPU with, lets say, 4 threads in each core, I can process 32 pixels(bits) per clock cycle, so 64*10^9 pixels/second = 1000 x 1000/ 0.00016s. So I am asking for any ready implementation with lower than O(3*n) complexity, which in a binary image I believe is possible.

Comment: timeit.timeit(lambda:im+1,number=100)/100 gives 8.358001708984375e-05 secs, so it's better than I thought, I need an algorithm with less than O(4*n) complexity

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I picked the fastest one with `cv2.findContours` to speed that up. In it, we could replace those expensive `transpose` and converting to tuple parts with simple [`slicing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing), like so -

```
idx = cv2.findContours(im,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)[1][0]
out = np.zeros_like(im)
out[idx[:,0,0],idx[:,0,1]] = 255
```

Runtime test -

```
In [114]: # Inputs
     ...: im=np.zeros((1000,1000),dtype=np.uint8)
     ...: im[400:600,400:600]=255
     ...: idx = cv2.findContours(im,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)[1][0]
     ...: 

In [115]: def original_app(im, idx):
     ...:     points=np.transpose(idx)
     ...:     tmp=np.zeros_like(im)
     ...:     tmp[tuple(points)]=255
     ...:     return tmp
     ...: 
     ...: def proposed_app(im, idx):
     ...:     out = np.zeros_like(im)
     ...:     out[idx[:,0,0],idx[:,0,1]] = 255
     ...:     return out
     ...: 

In [120]: %timeit original_app(im, idx)
10000 loops, best of 3: 108 µs per loop

In [121]: %timeit proposed_app(im, idx)
10000 loops, best of 3: 101 µs per loop

In [122]: %timeit cv2.findContours(im,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.55 ms per loop
```

So, there's some marginal improvement there with the proposed method, but that seems negligible compared to the contour-finding itself.

I looked into [`scikit-image's version`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.find_contours) and ran a quick test and seems like it's much slower than OpenCV version.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. All right, so the slicing indeed accelerates the algorithm. As you have noted above, findContours is the one, which is time-consuming. The problem is that findContours also has varying computation time, depending on the complexity of the binary shape, with Ω(findContours) a lot bigger than other ways, even 10 times more (unfortunately I was not able to find a good representative image to picture this fact).

Comment: I guess by using cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE would make findContours faster, but what is bad is the fact that I can not use binary numpy array as input, which would, in my view, accelerate a lot the function as a whole, by reducing to 1/8 the time needed to access and retrieve memory, and offer me a way faster runtime. Anyways, thank you again for your time.