# Create mask or boundary from each other in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, mask, scikit-image, opencv, python

I would like to get the mask from images with boundaries or boundaries from images of masks.

Here are two images:

[image: Mask Image]
[image: Boundary Image]

I went through the followings, I did not understand the logic there:
[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33077851/opencv-detect-boundary-and-roi-mask), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51824455/marking-boundary-given-mask), [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61340514/how-to-create-a-boundary-mask-around-an-object), [link4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54605089/finding-object-boundaries-which-are-close-to-each-other)

thanks,
ilyas

Comment: MASK->CONTOUR: use findContours with RETR_EXTERNAL. CONTOUR->MASK: use findContours with RETR_TREE, use internal contours only (use contourArea [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42293993/5008845) ), then use drawContours. Try it out and come back if you have a specific programming problem and some code

Comment: @Miki I am not sure about the c++ code in the link you provided. Could you try with python3 and provide the code? I tried with watershed etc, but I could not. What I want to do: I would like to draw boundaries by hand for any the shapes (cell, nucleus, etc). Then, create a mask from these boundaries. Or instead of drawing boundaries, first I create mask by hand, then draw boundaries.

Comment: I found this: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40441910/fast-method-to-retrieve-contour-mask-from-a-binary-mask-in-python). `im = cv.imread('mask.png')` 
`im = cv.cvtColor(im,cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)`
`idx = cv2.findContours(im,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)[1][0]`
`out = np.zeros_like(im)`
`out[idx[:,0],idx[:,1]] = 255`

Comment: But still cannot create boundaries (second image), but if using gradient function, it gives some boundaries but not correct!

Comment: Now this [link] (https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contours_begin/py_contours_begin.html) helped a lot:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still do not understand the logic, however, one can create boundary from mask and mask from boundary.

```
import os
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

out = "mask_boundary.png"
inp = "mask.png"
im = cv2.imread(inp)
imgray = cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(imgray,127,255,0)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
tmp = np.zeros_like(im)
boundary = cv2.drawContours(tmp, contours, -1, (255,255,255), 1)
plt.imsave(out, boundary, cmap = "gray")


out = "boundary_mask.png"
inp = "mask_boundary.png"
im = cv2.imread(inp)
imgray = cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(imgray,0,255,0)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
tmp = np.zeros_like(im)
boundary = cv2.drawContours(tmp, contours, 0,(255,255,255), -1)
for i in range(1,len(contours)):
    boundary = cv2.drawContours(boundary, contours, i,(255,255,255), -1)

plt.imsave(out, boundary, cmap = "gray")



out = "boun_mask.png"
inp = "boundary.png"
im = cv2.imread(inp)
imgray = cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(imgray,0,255,0)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
tmp = np.zeros_like(im)
boundary = cv2.drawContours(tmp, contours, 0,(255,255,255), -1)
for i in range(1,len(contours)):
    boundary = cv2.drawContours(boundary, contours, i,(255,255,255), -1)

plt.imsave(out, boundary, cmap = "gray")
```

**Note:** using the mask image above, I first created boundary and then from this boundary I created mask. However, I could not convert all boundary above to mask, especially the one at the image edges/border. It looks like there must be boundary at the border as well! **Any help on that will be appreciated!**

convert the above mask to boundary:

[image: mask2boundary]

now convert the new boundary to mask:

[image: newboundary2mask]

now convert the above boundary to mask:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

from this [link](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contours_begin/py_contours_begin.html) one can use the following;

to get boundary from mask:

```
im = cv2.imread('mask.png')
imgray = cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(imgray,127,255,0)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
tmp = np.zeros_like(im)
boundary = cv2.drawContours(tmp, contours, -1, (255,255,255), 1)
boundary[boundary > 0] = 255
plt.imsave("mask_boundary.png", boundary, cmap = "gray")
```

[image]